# External CSS not loading in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning

I have created new css file at root of the static resource as Layout.css which is public.

when I am including this css file in my .cmp file, I am not able to load it. I have even debugged and seen in network tab it is not even queried.

```
  <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.PicOSLayout}"/>
```

Need your help for this. Any suggestions.

Comment: try with `/resource/PicOSLayout`

Comment: I have the same problem since today. I notice it just generates an empty <link> tag in the header. The scripts are still being loaded via ltng:require, but not the styles.

Comment: Same here - I added the question to dev forum here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Developer_Forums&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&id=9060G000000XdPuQAK Edit: couldn't add it as comment as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Look for update in the org; disable those update